# Shiny Stock Chart Error: chartSeries requires an xtsible object

Tags: r, xts, shiny-server

I have the following code. I want to take the input of a valid stock symbol and render a candlestick plot. I want to give the user the option to switch between 20, 50, and 200 day simple moving averages on the plot as well. However, when I run the app, the mainPanel returns:

```
Error: chartSeries requires an xtsible object.
```

This is my first Shiny App development and I am at a loss as to why it is not working.

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)
library(lubridate)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Candlestick Stock Charts"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textInput("symb", "Input a Valid Stock Symbol", "AAPL"),

            radioButtons("radioMoveAvg",
                         "Moving Averages",
                         c("20-day" = "twentyAvg",
                           "50-day" = "fiftyAvg", 
                           "200-day" = "twohundAvg"))
        ),

        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("candleStick")
        )
    )
))

library(shiny)
library(quantmod)
library(lubridate)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    cs<-reactive({
        getSymbols(input$symb,
                   src = "yahoo",
                   from = Sys.Date()-years(2),
                   to = Sys.Date(),
                   auto.assign = FALSE)[, 4]

    })

    moveAvg<-reactive({
        if(input$radioMoveAvg=="twentyAvg"){
            x = 20
            col = "blue"
        }
        if(input$radioMoveAvg=="fiftyAvg"){
            x = 50
            col = "green"
        }
        if(input$radioMoveAvg=="twohundAvg"){
            x = 200
            col = "pink"
        }
    })

    output$candleStick <- renderPlot({
        candleChart(cs, up.col = "black", dn.col = "red", theme = "white", subset = "2019-01-01/")
        addSMA(moveAvg)
    })
})
```

Comment: Found the errors in my code. Removed the lubridate package because it was not needed in the getSymbols function. Moved the addSMA function into the moveAvg reactive statement. The code is working as I pictured when I began the project.

Answer (score 0):

Found the errors in my code. Removed the lubridate package because it was not needed in the getSymbols function. Moved the addSMA function into the moveAvg reactive statement. The code is working as I pictured when I began the project.